# Excel formula nested If statments return empty row if there's no value for vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, nested-if

```
=IF(B10="","",IF(VLOOKUP(B10,'Template'!A:B,2,FALSE)<$I$4,"No longer use",""))
```

So far I have excel formula like this, but I would like to modify code to when there's no value for vlookup return empty row instead of #NA. Is there any way to modify it like that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap in an IFERROR()

```
=IF(B10="","",IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(B10,'Template'!A:B,2,FALSE)<$I$4,"No longer use",""),""))
```

Or we can return a ridiculously large number instead:

```
=IF(B10="","",IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B10,'Template'!A:B,2,FALSE),1E+99)<$I$4,"No longer use",""))
```